# Laravel 5.2 belongsTo relationship with condition not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I go problem with `belongsTo()` relationship as the following.

My Model

```
class TypeOne extends Model{

}
===============================
class TypeTwo extends Model{

}
===============================
class Post extends Model{
    public function typeOne(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Type','type_id')->where('object_type','type_one');
    }
    public function typeTwo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Type','type_id')->where('object_type','type_two');
    }

    public function getPost(){
        return Post::with(['typeOne','typeTwo'])->get();
    }
}
```

And I will get error `column "object_type" does not exist`

What should I do with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the relationship function, Please model as properly.

May be this is also make an error. If already you **Type** model..
  Do you have **Type** model..?

You need to use **polymorphic** concept for this situation.

[polymorphic laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: I have TypeOne & TypeTwo model. When I use `where('object_type','type_one');` or `where('object_type','type_two')` , I got error `column "object_type" does not exist`. This mean that laravel assume `object_type` is field of TypeOne or TypeTwo. But  `object_type` is in Post Model

Comment: @RichatCHHAYVANDY note that.. Okay try with my above code which small correction in the model mention place. i.e., belongsTo('TypeOne') or belongsTo('TypeTwo') and say after that.. Please...

Comment: Thank for your code. I have tried, but I got the same error. Do you have any thing else?

Comment: @RichatCHHAYVANDY if you don not have object_type in the TypeOne/TypeTow model, then you cannot use where condition here..

Comment: @RichatCHHAYVANDY Use without where condition in the two functions first and say do you get any answer and that answer is okay for you..?

Comment: so I can not use one table has many relationships with other table in the same field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124214/discussion-between-richat-chhayvandy-and-rama-durai).

Comment: Thanks you! And if you are not in the same namespace, you need to add this to `App\Providers/AppServiceProvider` in boot function
`Relation::morphMap([
            'post' => Post::class
        ]);`